# Compiling cumulus v0.9.36 with --no-default-features

Tags: wasm, substrate-parachain-template, cumulus

When attempting to compile `cumulus` on branch `polkadot-v0.9.36` while disabling standard features, this error occurs:

```
nologik@nologik-laptop dkg-substrate % cargo check --workspace --no-default-features
⚡ Found 3 strongly connected components which includes at least one cycle each
cycle(001) ∈ α: DisputeCoordinator ~~{"DisputeDistributionMessage"}~~> DisputeDistribution ~~{"DisputeCoordinatorMessage"}~~>  *
cycle(002) ∈ β: CandidateBacking ~~{"ProvisionerMessage"}~~> Provisioner ~~{"CandidateBackingMessage"}~~>  *
cycle(003) ∈ γ: NetworkBridgeRx ~~{"GossipSupportMessage"}~~> GossipSupport ~~{"NetworkBridgeRxMessage"}~~>  *
    Checking cumulus-pallet-parachain-system v0.1.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus?branch=release-v0.9.360#27c57ba6)
    Checking cumulus-pallet-xcmp-queue v0.1.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus?branch=release-v0.9.360#27c57ba6)
    Checking dkg-standalone-node v3.0.0 (/Users/nologik/commonwealth/dkg-substrate/standalone/node)
error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
    --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/xcmp-queue/src/lib.rs:1006:25
     |
1006 |                         message_metadata: vec![(sent_at, format)],
     |                                           ^^^
     |
     = note: consider importing one of these items:
             codec::alloc::vec
             scale_info::prelude::vec
             sp_std::vec

error: cannot find macro `vec` in this scope
   --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/lib.rs:698:17
    |
698 |                         provides: vec![hash.as_ref().to_vec()],
    |                                   ^^^
    |
    = note: consider importing one of these items:
            codec::alloc::vec
            scale_info::prelude::vec
            sp_std::vec

error: cannot find macro `thread_local` in this scope
  --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/mod.rs:37:1
   |
37 | environmental::environmental!(VALIDATION_PARAMS: ValidationParams);
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `thread_local` is in scope, but it is an attribute: `#[thread_local]`
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::thread_local_impl` which comes from the expansion of the macro `environmental::environmental` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_read` in module `sp_io::storage`
  --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:81:19
   |
81 |         sp_io::storage::host_read.replace_implementation(host_storage_read),
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sp_io::storage`

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_set` in module `sp_io::storage`
  --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:82:19
   |
82 |         sp_io::storage::host_set.replace_implementation(host_storage_set),
   |                         ^^^^^^^^ not found in `sp_io::storage`

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_get` in module `sp_io::storage`
  --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:83:19
   |
83 |         sp_io::storage::host_get.replace_implementation(host_storage_get),
   |                         ^^^^^^^^ not found in `sp_io::storage`

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_exists` in module `sp_io::storage`
  --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:84:19
   |
84 |         sp_io::storage::host_exists.replace_implementation(host_storage_exists),
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sp_io::storage`

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_clear` in module `sp_io::storage`
  --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:85:19
   |
85 |         sp_io::storage::host_clear.replace_implementation(host_storage_clear),
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sp_io::storage`

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_root` in module `sp_io::storage`
  --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:86:19
   |
86 |         sp_io::storage::host_root.replace_implementation(host_storage_root),
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sp_io::storage`

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_clear_prefix` in module `sp_io::storage`
   --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:87:19
    |
87  |           sp_io::storage::host_clear_prefix.replace_implementation(host_storage_clear_prefix),
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: a function with a similar name exists: `clear_prefix`
    |
   ::: /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/cb4f249/primitives/io/src/lib.rs:167:5
    |
167 | /     /// Clear the storage of each key-value pair where the key starts with the given `prefix`.
168 | |     ///
169 | |     /// # Limit
170 | |     ///
...   |
194 | |         Externalities::clear_prefix(*self, prefix, limit, None).into()
195 | |     }
    | |_____- similarly named function `clear_prefix` defined here

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_append` in module `sp_io::storage`
  --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:88:19
   |
88 |         sp_io::storage::host_append.replace_implementation(host_storage_append),
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sp_io::storage`

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_next_key` in module `sp_io::storage`
  --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:89:19
   |
89 |         sp_io::storage::host_next_key.replace_implementation(host_storage_next_key),
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sp_io::storage`

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_start_transaction` in module `sp_io::storage`
   --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:90:19
    |
90  |           sp_io::storage::host_start_transaction
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: a function with a similar name exists: `start_transaction`
    |
   ::: /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/cb4f249/primitives/io/src/lib.rs:285:5
    |
285 | /     /// Start a new nested transaction.
286 | |     ///
287 | |     /// This allows to either commit or roll back all changes that are made after this call.
288 | |     /// For every transaction there must be a matching call to either `rollback_transaction`
...   |
298 | |         self.storage_start_transaction();
299 | |     }
    | |_____- similarly named function `start_transaction` defined here

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_rollback_transaction` in module `sp_io::storage`
   --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:92:19
    |
92  |           sp_io::storage::host_rollback_transaction
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: a function with a similar name exists: `rollback_transaction`
    |
   ::: /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/cb4f249/primitives/io/src/lib.rs:301:5
    |
301 | /     /// Rollback the last transaction started by `start_transaction`.
302 | |     ///
303 | |     /// Any changes made during that transaction are discarded.
304 | |     ///
...   |
310 | |             .expect("No open transaction that can be rolled back.");
311 | |     }
    | |_____- similarly named function `rollback_transaction` defined here

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_commit_transaction` in module `sp_io::storage`
   --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:94:19
    |
94  |           sp_io::storage::host_commit_transaction
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: a function with a similar name exists: `commit_transaction`
    |
   ::: /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/cb4f249/primitives/io/src/lib.rs:313:5
    |
313 | /     /// Commit the last transaction started by `start_transaction`.
314 | |     ///
315 | |     /// Any changes made during that transaction are committed.
316 | |     ///
...   |
322 | |             .expect("No open transaction that can be committed.");
323 | |     }
    | |_____- similarly named function `commit_transaction` defined here

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_get` in module `sp_io::default_child_storage`
  --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:96:33
   |
96 |         sp_io::default_child_storage::host_get
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^ not found in `sp_io::default_child_storage`

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_read` in module `sp_io::default_child_storage`
  --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:98:33
   |
98 |         sp_io::default_child_storage::host_read
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sp_io::default_child_storage`

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_set` in module `sp_io::default_child_storage`
   --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:100:33
    |
100 |         sp_io::default_child_storage::host_set
    |                                       ^^^^^^^^ not found in `sp_io::default_child_storage`

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_clear` in module `sp_io::default_child_storage`
   --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:102:33
    |
102 |         sp_io::default_child_storage::host_clear
    |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sp_io::default_child_storage`

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_storage_kill` in module `sp_io::default_child_storage`
   --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:104:33
    |
104 |           sp_io::default_child_storage::host_storage_kill
    |                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: a function with a similar name exists: `storage_kill`
    |
   ::: /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/cb4f249/primitives/io/src/lib.rs:398:5
    |
398 | /     /// Clear a child storage key.
399 | |     ///
400 | |     /// See `Storage` module `clear_prefix` documentation for `limit` usage.
401 | |     #[version(3)]
...   |
404 | |         self.kill_child_storage(&child_info, limit, None).into()
405 | |     }
    | |_____- similarly named function `storage_kill` defined here

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_exists` in module `sp_io::default_child_storage`
   --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:106:33
    |
106 |         sp_io::default_child_storage::host_exists
    |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sp_io::default_child_storage`

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_clear_prefix` in module `sp_io::default_child_storage`
   --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:108:33
    |
108 |           sp_io::default_child_storage::host_clear_prefix
    |                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: a function with a similar name exists: `clear_prefix`
    |
   ::: /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/cb4f249/primitives/io/src/lib.rs:438:5
    |
438 | /     /// Clear the child storage of each key-value pair where the key starts with the given `prefix`.
439 | |     ///
440 | |     /// See `Storage` module `clear_prefix` documentation for `limit` usage.
441 | |     #[version(2)]
...   |
449 | |         self.clear_child_prefix(&child_info, prefix, limit, None).into()
450 | |     }
    | |_____- similarly named function `clear_prefix` defined here

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_root` in module `sp_io::default_child_storage`
   --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:110:33
    |
110 |         sp_io::default_child_storage::host_root
    |                                       ^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sp_io::default_child_storage`

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_next_key` in module `sp_io::default_child_storage`
   --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:112:33
    |
112 |         sp_io::default_child_storage::host_next_key
    |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sp_io::default_child_storage`

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_set` in module `sp_io::offchain_index`
   --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:114:26
    |
114 |         sp_io::offchain_index::host_set.replace_implementation(host_offchain_index_set),
    |                                ^^^^^^^^ not found in `sp_io::offchain_index`

error[E0425]: cannot find value `host_clear` in module `sp_io::offchain_index`
   --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:115:26
    |
115 |         sp_io::offchain_index::host_clear.replace_implementation(host_offchain_index_clear),
    |                                ^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `sp_io::offchain_index`

error[E0425]: cannot find value `GLOBAL` in this scope
  --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/mod.rs:37:1
   |
37 | environmental::environmental!(VALIDATION_PARAMS: ValidationParams);
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `environmental::environmental` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error: could not compile `cumulus-pallet-xcmp-queue` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error[E0061]: this function takes 4 arguments but 3 arguments were supplied
   --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/27c57ba/pallets/parachain-system/src/validate_block/implementation.rs:191:16
    |
191 |     let mut ext = Ext::<B>::new(&mut overlay, &mut cache, backend);
    |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^----------------------------------- an argument of type `core::option::Option<&mut Extensions>` is missing
    |
note: associated function defined here
   --> /Users/nologik/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/cb4f249/primitives/state-machine/src/ext.rs:128:9
    |
128 |     pub fn new(
    |            ^^^
help: provide the argument
    |
191 |     let mut ext = Ext::<B>::new(&mut overlay, &mut cache, backend, /* core::option::Option<&mut Extensions> */);
    |                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0061, E0425.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0061`.
error: could not compile `cumulus-pallet-parachain-system` due to 29 previous errors
nologik@nologik-laptop dkg-substrate %
```

This error can be mitigated by not passing `--no-default-features`, however, this is a necessary flag to allow compiling to WASM.